# How to concatenate timestamp using awk

Tags: unix

I am using below command to grep timestamp from a log file. However i'd like to remove the millisecond (.222) string from the output. Now sure how to use either -F or sed command to achieve the desired output.

```
$ grep -h "command begin" /u01/test.log | tail -n 1|awk '{print $1,$2}' 

2023-03-13 23:34:17.222
```

Comment: Please show use **sample input** & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `awk '{sub(/\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/,"", $2); print $1, $2}'` . Good luck.

Comment: ? I shouldn't thank you, because since 21h, there's no more required  informations provided.